# "In the way" or "on the way" when referring to an actual location

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Searching for the difference between “in the way” and “on the way”, I found that the first means an obstacle while the latter means something in progression. This difference is always stressed, so I can’t tell which one to use when referring to “way” as a concrete noun, as a physic location.

*-There are many ways that lead to the green lake. In/on one of these ways, a native woman is hunting.*

*-In/on the ways of Mojave, I became a better person.*

Which one (*in* or *on*) is correct or preferable in this context?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Along (2) A preposition won't work here. You want something like 'Following' or '[By] immersing myself in'.

Comment: Note that, in the two examples, the phrase has two entirely different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

If the woman is moving along the ways to hunt, "on."  Otherwise, it would probably need to be paraphrased to have its intended meaning.

If the person became a better person while traveling, "on" -- otherwise, "among" to indicate "in the place where those ways are."

Answer (score 0):

The use of *either* preposition makes the sentence confusing and difficult to understand.

Both *in the way* and *on the way* are set expressions, in which *way* is ***not*** understood to mean *way* in the sense being used.

The following all come from Merriam-Webster's definition of [*way*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way):

> **in one's way** *or less commonly* **in the way**
> **1** : in a position to be encountered by one : in or along one's course
>      // an opportunity had been put *in my way*
>      — Ellen Glasgow
> **2** : in a position to hinder or obstruct
>
> **on the way** or **on one's way**
> : moving along in one's course : in progress

---

The use of the singular noun *way* as used in the example sentence in the question, outside of these set phrases, has the following definition:

> **1 a** : a thoroughfare for travel or transportation from place to place

But using either *in the way* or *on the way* (or even *by the way*, which is another set expression with a different meaning) will only cause confusion.

---

As such, and after eliminating these prepositions, the preposition that you probably want to use in order to emphasize the sense of *way* as location is **at**:

> ✔ There are many ways that lead to the green lake. ***At*** one of these ways, a native woman is hunting.

Since there is no set expression that uses *at this way* or *at the way*, the noun can be parsed out as something separate without confusion.

---

Alternatively, if the use of *way* will cause confusion no matter what, consider replacing it with something different such as [*waypoint*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waypoint). But even if you use *waypoint*, I would probably still use *at* as the preposition:

> There are many *waypoints* that lead to the green lake. *At* one of these *waypoints*, a native woman is hunting.